# Remove white space in CSS marquee

Tags: css, wordpress, marquee

I am trying to add a marquee effect with CSS3 animation in Wordpress as it doesn't support the `<marquee>` tag. I would like to get rid of the white space in between each loop. I tried using nowrap but it doesn't work.

```css
@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    text-indent: 430px
  }
  100% {
    text-indent: -485px
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    text-indent: 430px
  }
  100% {
    text-indent: -485px
  }
}

.marquee {
  font-size: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: marquee 12s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: marquee 12s linear infinite;
}

.marquee:hover {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee">
  <a href="#">
    SOON SOON SOON SOON SOON SOON SOON </a></p>
```

Link here: http://www.houseofbase.fr/preview/wordpress/comingsoon/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to using `text-indent` for transform. Use this instead of your animation:

```
@keyframes marquee {
0% {
transform: translateX(100vw);
 }
100% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
   }
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
  }
100% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
  }
}
```

```css
@keyframes marquee {
0% {
transform: translateX(100vw);
 }
100% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
   }
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
  }
100% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
  }
}
.marquee {
  font-size: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: marquee 12s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: marquee 12s linear infinite;
}

.marquee:hover {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee">
  <a href="#">
    SOON SOON SOON SOON SOON SOON SOON </a></p>
```

Comment: The end of link is not visible because of `overflow: hidden` of its parent `<p>`

Comment: Hi Alie Suvélor. if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this do what you want.

```css
.marquee {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.marquee-content {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}
.item-collection-1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0%;
  animation: swap 10s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes swap {
  0%, 50% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  50.01%,
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
.marquee-content:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused
}
.item1 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: 500px;
  background: cyan;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.item2 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: 500px;
  background: magenta;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
/* Transition */

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <div class="marquee-content">
    <span class="item-collection-1">
    <span class="item1"><a href="http://www.google.com">soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon</a></span>
    <span class="item1"><a href="http://www.google.com">soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon</a></span>

    </span>
    <span class="item-collection-2">
    <span class="item2"><a href="http://www.google.com">soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon</a></span>
    <span class="item2"><a href="http://www.google.com">soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon soon</a></span>

    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if i understand but try use **margin-left** negative like:

```
.marquee a{ margin-left: -50%; }
```

Comment: Maybe it works now, because it has repeated text and it seems good working. But it shift totally the marquee to left.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi what about the set translateX more than just -100vw? -150vw maybe

Comment: No it is a bad coding. The problem must be remove truly.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.marquee {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-grid;
}
```